# Webpack configuration issue: Need help resolving errors in my webpack.config.js file

Tags: html, reactjs, node.js, tailwind-css, webpack-dev-server

## webpack.config.js

> I'm encountering an issue with my route URLs. When I navigate from the blog to a specific blog details page like 'blog/blog-01.html', everything works fine. However, when I click on the header to go back to the home page or any other page, my URL becomes 'blog/index.html' instead of the actual '/index.html' it should be. How can I fix this inconsistency?

```
const glob = require('glob');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const INCLUDE_PATTERN = /<include src="(.+)"\s*\/?>(?:<\/include>)?/gi;

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
      watch: true,
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
    allowedHosts: "all",
    hot: true,
    liveReload: true,
    open: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    clean: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: (pathData) => {
            // Example: Place all images in an 'images' folder in the output directory
            const relativePath = path.relative(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), pathData.filename);
            return `${relativePath.split(path.sep).join('/')}`; // Adjust the path as needed
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    ...generateHTMLPlugins(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css',
      chunkFilename: 'style.css',
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "./src/images", to: "images" },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};

function processIncludes(filePath) {
  let content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
  content = content.replace(INCLUDE_PATTERN, (match, p1) => {
    const includePath = path.resolve(path.dirname(filePath), p1);
    if (fs.existsSync(includePath)) {
      return fs.readFileSync(includePath, 'utf8');
    }
    return '';
  });
  return content;
}

function generateHTMLPlugins() {
  return glob.sync('./src/**/*.html').map((dir) => {
    const filename = path.relative('./src', dir);
    const formattedFilename = filename.split(path.sep).join('/');
    var outputFilename = path.join(path.dirname(formattedFilename), path.basename(formattedFilename));
    // Process includes directly in memory
  
    const processedContent = processIncludes(dir);
    return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: outputFilename,
      templateContent: processedContent, // Use processed HTML content directly
      favicon: './src/images/favicon.ico',
      inject: 'body',
    });
  });
}
```